# Using Localstorage to store and retrieve javascript variables from one html page to another (DOM)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, local-storage

I have one html page `1.html` and i want to get some text content and store it to a `js.js` file using jquery to get the text by id.

This code only works in `1.html` page, **where the text I want to copy from is** but **not** in `2.html` file.

Here is my code. Note that it works if I store text inside localstorage setter second parameter.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
         var c1Title= $('#r1c1Title').text();

//changing c1Title to any String content like "test" will work

    localStorage.setItem("t1",c1Title);
        var result = localStorage.getItem("t1");

        $("#title1").html(result);
        alert(result);
    });
```

Here is the complete demo I am working on [Github](https://github.com/csandreas1/LocalStorage):

Comment: use `localstorage` for that

Comment: @chiragsatapara how?

Comment: Use local storage

Comment: @Eternal , refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp. Let me give you sample example in answer

Comment: You can achieve via local storage and Here you need to make sure that you are setting this local storage value in parent html page or parent js file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)

Comment: @BenFortune my question is different, I want to store a dom variable not a plain text.

Comment: @Eternal That's not what your question's asking.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use either **localStorage** or **cookies**.

### With localStorage

On the first page, use the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem("variableName", "variableContent")
```

That sets a localStorage variable of `variableName` for the domain, with the content `variableContent`. *You can change these names and values to whatever you want, they are just used as an example*

On the second page, get the value using the following code:

```
localStorage.getItem("variableName")
```

That will return the value stored in `variableName`, which is `variableContent`.

### Notes

- There is a 5MB limit on the amount of data you can store in localStorage.
- You can remove items using `localStorage.removeItem("variableName")`.
- Depending on where you are, you may need to take a look at the [cookie policy](http://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/) (this effects all forms of websites storing data on a computer, not just cookies). **This is important, as otherwise using any of these solutions may be illegal.**
- If you only want to store data until the user closes their browser, you can use sessionStorage instead (just change `localStorage` to `sessionStorage` in all instances of your code)
- If you want to be able to use the variable value on the server as well, use cookies instead - check out [cookies on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
- For more information on localStorage, check out [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or [this one on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: what if I want to set the variable content to be the variable that i store the elementbyid text()?

Comment: I use      localStorage.setItem("t1",c1Title);  this works on blog.html but I get empty text in other files

Comment: @Eternal Make sure that you're not using `localStorage.setItem()` on the second page (otherwise it would overwrite the values), and that you are using **exactly** the same key on both pages.

Comment: see my GitHub demo in my question

Comment: The content i get from js is invisible until  i visit the page that has the setters,  how can i fix that?

Comment: @csandreas1 You need to get the data and do something with it - the getters will only give you back what is stored - for example if you did `document.body.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("variableName");` would set the contents of the body to the contents of the localStorage variable

Comment: I did something like that to print them:  `var result  = localStorage.getItem("tit1");`  then     `$("#ti1").html(result);`

Comment: see my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409988/localstorage-content-is-invisible-until-i-visit-the-page-with-the-setters

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this code. It's better to use **local storage**.

> Here you need to make sure that you are setting this local storage
>   value in parent html page or parent js file.

**create local storage**

> localStorage.setItem("{itemlable}", {itemvalue});

```
localStorage.setItem("variable1", $('#r1c1Title').text());
localStorage.setItem("variable2", $('#r1c2Title').text());
```

**Get local storage value**

> localStorage.getItem("{itemlable}")

```
alert(localStorage.getItem("variable1") + ' Second variable ::: '+ localStorage.getItem("variable2"));
```

For more information follow this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**If you wanted to store in div then follow this code.**

**Html Code**

```
<div class="div_data"></div>
```

**Js code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("variable1", "Value 1");
            localStorage.setItem("variable2", "Value 2");
                $(".div_data").html(' First variable ::: '+localStorage.getItem("variable1") + ' Second variable ::: '+ localStorage.getItem("variable2"));
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't work when I put that code inside $( document ).ready(function() {

Comment: Make sure that you have included jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use local storage as mentioned in above comments. Please find below how to write in javascript.

> Local Storage Pros and Cons

**Pros:**

1. Web storage can be viewed simplistically as an improvement on cookies, providing much greater storage capacity.
2. 5120KB (5MB which equals 2.5 Million chars on Chrome) is the default storage size for an entire domain.
3. This gives you considerably more space to work with than a typical 4KB cookie.
4. The data is not sent back to the server for every HTTP request (HTML, images, JavaScript, CSS, etc) - reducing the amount of traffic between client and server.
5. The data stored in localStorage persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

**Cons:**

It works on same-origin policy. So, data stored will only be available on the same origin.
    // Store value in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("c1Title", $('#r1c1Title').text());

```
// Retrieve value in local storage
localStorage.getItem("c1Title");
```

Your html div

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Add Javascript Code

```
$('#output').html(localStorage.getItem("c1Title"));
```

Let me know if it not works

Comment: so how can I use that to print it in the html?

Comment: it works in blog.html but I get empty text in other documents see demo https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FI1YXKN89S0T

Comment: I just check the link provided by you and it seems working fine. Can you please show me exact error?

Comment: the problem isn't an error. The problem is that I can't see the text in any other file than blog.html. The text i store in the variable c1Title is inside blog.html file

Comment: @Eternal: Because of your last comment, I have checked the same code in my local machine and its working perfect. If still its not working on your hand than kindly share your code where you have implemented this. So I can take a look and help to get it done.

Comment: Please check here, I have created demo for you on GitHub. https://shyamshingadiya.github.io/localStorageDemo/

Comment: your demo is different. I have posted a GitHub link in my question. I am trying to parse dom variable inside Localstorage. This doesn't work on any other files than the file I retrieve the text from.

Comment: Definitely it will not work with your code because you have appended scripts file in each page. When you go in 2.html page your js file will search for data again to store in local storage. So what you need to do is remove `setItem` from js file and add that line in HTML page only. In another page you need to only retrieve data. Let me know if it still not work.

Comment: still doesn't work, help me so I will be the first to make your reputation 2k :)

Comment: Just remove your script.js file from your code and follow my GitHub code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150484/discussion-between-shyam-shingadiya-and-eternal).

Comment: `https://shyamshingadiya.github.io/LocalStorage/1.html`
In this page data is saved in local storage,in `https://shyamshingadiya.github.io/LocalStorage/2.html`,`https://shyamshingadiya.github.io/LocalStorage/3.html`,
`https://shyamshingadiya.github.io/LocalStorage/4.html` You got data from local storage

Comment: Why the content is not visible until you visit the page that has the setters? check here at the bottom: http://www.mpoliasma.top the page that has the content is http://www.mpoliasma.top/blog/blog.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a common.js file and modified this and save.

```
Session = (function () {
    var instance;
    function init() {
        var sessionIdKey = "UserLoggedIn";
        return {
            // Public methods and variables.
            set: function (sessionData) {
                window.localStorage.setItem(sessionIdKey, JSON.stringify(sessionData));
                return true;
            },
            get: function () {
                var result = null;
                try {
                    result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(sessionIdKey));
                } catch (e) { }
                return result;
            }
        };
    };
    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = init();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
}());


function isSessionActive() {
    var session = Session.getInstance().get();
    if (session != null) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


function clearSession() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.localStorage.removeItem("CampolUserLoggedIn");
    window.location.assign("/Account/Login.aspx");
}
```

Insert like this.

```
$(function () {
    if (!isSessionActive()) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.ID = 1;
        obj.Name = "Neeraj Pathak";
        obj.OrganizationID = 1;
        obj.Email = "npathak56@gmail.com";
        Session.getInstance().set(obj);
    }

    ///clearSession();
});
```

get like this way

```
  LoggedinUserDetails = Session.getInstance().get();
```

Comment: Why does OP need something this complicated when they can simply call `localStorage.setItem(item, value)` and `localStorage.getItem(item)`?