# Localstorage and DOM: Content is invisible until i visit the page with the setters

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, local-storage

This is the [website](http://mpoliasma.top), if you scroll down at the bottom you will notice everything is invisible: This probably has to do with DOM conflict with LocalStorage.

[image]

When you visit the [page](http://www.mpoliasma.top/blog/blog.php) with the setters, and go back to the home page you will notice the content is coming back.

Here is my code:

**Page with the setters** (Parent file):

```
//code is at the end of the body of the page

    localStorage.setItem("tit1",$('#r1c1Title').text());
    localStorage.setItem("tit2",$('#r1c2Title').text());

   localStorage.setItem("l1",document.getElementById("r1c1Link").href);
   localStorage.setItem("l2",document.getElementById("r1c2Link").href);

  localStorage.setItem("im1",$('#r1c1Image').attr('src'));
   localStorage.setItem("im2",$('#r1c2Image').attr('src'));
```

`custom.js` included in every other html file:

```
 //Retrieve Titles
    var result  = localStorage.getItem("tit1");
    var result2 = localStorage.getItem("tit2");

     //Retrieve Links
     var r3= localStorage.getItem("l1");
     var r33= localStorage.getItem("l2");

     //Retrieve Image SRCs
     var r4 = localStorage.getItem("im1");
     var r44 = localStorage.getItem("im2");



    //print titles
    $("#ti1").html(result);
    $("#ti2").html(result2);

   //print links
    $("#link1").attr("href", r3);
    $("#link2").attr("href", r33);

   //print images
       $("#img1").attr("src",r4);
       $("#img2").attr("src",r44);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the items in storage in your index page but in the other pages. In the index page, you have just used `custom.js` that seems to be getting items rather than setting. So flow you are doing is, getting the item from the storage from index page(which does not exist) and then only setting item to the storage from other page(and of course, the user can sees the second time he goes to the index page because of this). You need to set the item first.

Comment: i add the setters in the index page and it Is the same thing

Comment: @Eternal can you make a plunkr.. if you have set the item first and then get it, it must work(if everything else is fine)

Comment: I shouldn't set the item every time right? I have put the setters inside the file I want to grab the content. Then I use js with the getters and DOM, in the other html files I want to add the content that it Is saved in localstorage

Comment: yes, of course but if the user is new, something needs to be done in the index page if you want the title to be grabbed. From the website, i don't see a place where you have done that. A IF check if the item exist, and if it does not exist then, you can set the item. If you keep the setters only in certain page, you cannot expect the getters to return value in index page if the user is new(because there's no setter from index page for new user).

Comment: I can put setters in index file butI can't grab with DOM an item that is in DIFFERENT file

Comment: what are you expecting then, for your artitecture to work? You already know the fault. You should change your flow anyways :). either you could hide it for new users or design it in  a way you could set in from index page